# Grep --exclude-dir (root directory only)

Tags: grep

I'm trying to setup a grep command, that searches my current directory, but excludes a directory, only if it's the root directory.

So for the following directories, I want #1 to be excluded, and #2 to be included

```
1) vendor/phpunit
2) app/views/vendor
```

I originally started with the below command

```
grep -Ir --exclude-dir=vendor keywords *
```

I tried using ^vendor, ^vendor/, ^vendor/*, ^vendor*, but nothing seems to work.

Is there a way to do this with grep? I was looking to try to do it with one grep call, but if I have to, I can pipe the results to a second grep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pipes:

```
grep -Ir keywords * | grep -v '^vendor/'
```

The problem with `exclude-dir` is, it tests the name of the directory and not the path before going into it, so it is not possible to distinguish between two `vendor` directories based on their depths.

Comment: This is useless - it doesn't actually exclude the directory, it just ignores the results. Imagine you have a directory tree totalling a few mb, with a single gb folder in it. Can you imagine why you might want to exclude that folder from the search?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better solution, which will actually ignore the specified directory:

```
function grepex(){
    excludedir="$1"
    shift;
    for i in *; do
        if [ "$i" != "$excludedir" ]; then
            grep $@ "$i"
        fi
    done
}
```

You use it as a drop-in replacement to grep, just have the excluded dir as the first argument and leave the * off the end. So, your command would look like:

```
grepex vendor -Ir keywords
```

It's not perfect, but as long as you don't have any really weird folders (e.g. with names like `--` or something), it will cover most use cases. Feel free to refine it if you want something more elaborate.